# Problems clicking List Items with checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I've been researching a way to 'favourite' list items for a while now, and I have a `ListView` with checkboxes where everything is displaying properly.

My problem is that I need the checkbox to be clickable and set the list item as checked, and separately I should be able to click the list item to start a new activity.

Currently, clicking the checkbox changes the icon like it should but doesn't set it as checked, whereas clicking the list item sets the item as checked.

In this current code, I haven't included the intent to start the new activity on item click; all I'd like at the moment is for the item to be 'checked' when the checkbox is clicked on.

**AndroidListViewActivity.java:**

```
package com.androidlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidListViewActivity extends Activity {

    ListView myList;
    Button getChoice;

    String[] listContent = {
            "January",
            "February",
            "March",
            "April",
            "May",
            "June",
            "July",
            "August",
            "September",
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        getChoice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getchoice);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.single_item, listContent);

        myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        getChoice.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String selected = "";

                int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
                SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for(int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++){
                    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                        selected += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";

                    }
                }

                Toast.makeText(AndroidListViewActivity.this, 
                        selected, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});

    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getchoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Choice" />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_favourites"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:focusable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/single_item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was the way you declared your `ArrayAdapter`

instead of doing like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    R.layout.list_item, R.id.single_item, listContent);
```

use this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent);
```

EDIT:

For custom adapter behavior, you'd have to make your own `Adapter`.

You could then add `onCheckedChangedListener` for the checkbox and `onClickListener` for the item click.

See [here](http://micropilot.tistory.com/entry/Android-ListView-with-CheckBox-item) for similar example

Comment: ah, thanks for the quick response. However, that's the default look and I'm declaring a custom look, using list_item.xml which I've provided the code for in my question

Comment: Okay, I've had a look at the example and it doesn't really improve on what I had already, but thanks for finding it. I'm pretty new to android and I'd kinda hoped to not have to make my own adapter, are you sure there's no simple thing eg. listView.setItemsCanFocus that I've missed?

Comment: Not that I know of. What you are basically doing now is trying to get Android to know that it should act as a list with multiple choice while telling him it's a normal list. Therefore it won't distinguish between your button and the checkbox. Custom adapter seems like the only way in my mind, becuase you need a custom behavior of a row in the list.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I'll try and get it working and also give it a bit of time to see if anyone has another answer, then I'll set yours as the answer to say thanks for helping!

Comment: did you find a better answer? if not, please up vote and accept.